# How to make "pretty rounding"?

Tags: r, rounding

I need to do a rounding like this and convert it as a character:

```
as.character(round(5.9999,2))
```

I expect it to become `6.00`, but it just gives me `6`

Is there anyway that I can make it show `6.00`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try either one of these:

```
> sprintf("%3.2f", round(5.9999, digits=2))
[1] "6.00
> sprintf("%3.2f", 5.999)  # no round needed either
[1] "6.00
```

There are also `formatC()` and `prettyNum()`.

Answer (score 2):

To help explain what's going on - the `round(5.9999, 2)` call is rounding your number to the nearest hundredths place, which gives you the *number* (not string) very close to (or exactly equal to, if you get lucky with floating-point representations) 6.00.  Then `as.character()` looks at that number, takes up to 15 significant digits of it (see `?as.character`) in order to represent it to sufficient accuracy, and determines that only 1 significant digit is necessary.  So that's what you get.

Answer (score -1):

As Dirk indicated, formatC() is another option.

formatC(x = 5.999, digits = 2, format = 'f')