# Rounding numbers in R

Tags: r, rounding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to make “pretty rounding” in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490196/how-to-make-pretty-rounding-in-r)

I have a number, say `1.036315`, which I want to round it to the firsts decimal place, so that the outcome is `1.0`, which should not be `1`, as I also want to state that the approximation is accurate to the first decimal place.

But when I use `round(1.036315, digits=1)`, R gives me `1`, which is something I don't want.

Any way for making R to present the thing I want?

Comment: _Exact_ duplicate of [how to make "pretty rounding" in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490196/how-to-make-pretty-rounding-in-r).  You asked the same question ~6 months ago using the same tags.  Please use the search function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sprintf("%.1f",1.036315)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: will formatC also do the trick? formatC(1.036315,digits=1,format="f")

Comment: I don't think sprintf rounds, it just truncates.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
format(round(1.036315, 1), nsmall = 1).
```

Other functions are `sprintf` and `formatC`

Comment: Here is a function version: roundlyr <- function(x,y) {
  round1 <- format(round(x, y), nsmall = y)
  return(round1)
}

Answer (score 0):

You could count up the whole number digits before you call round().  
`count = 0;`
`n = myNum;`
`while(n>=10){`
`n/=10;`
`count++;}`
`return round(myNum, digits=(count+1));`